# Improving speed of mySQL Query on a larger database

Tags: mysql, performance

I am trying to optimize an SQL query to hopefully increase the speed of its execution.

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entry` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `numDB` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `entry` (`entry`),
  UNIQUE KEY `entry_numDB` (`entry`,`numDB`),
  UNIQUE KEY `entry_numDB_id` (`id`,`entry`,`numDB`),
  KEY `numDB` (`numDB`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `details` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dataID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `dbID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  <removed - unimportant>
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `dataID` (`dataID`),
  KEY `dbID` (`dbID`),
  KEY `dataID_dbID` (`dataID`,`dbID`),
  <removed - unimportant>
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

An entry (e.g., 'abc') is stored in table data as "id = 1; entry = abc, numDB = 2" and has (at least) two entries in details "id = 1, dataID = 1, dbID = 4" and "id = 2, dataID = 1, dbID = 17", however the same dataID and dbID can occur multiple times, e.g., "id = 3, dataID = 1, dbID = 17", "id = 4, dataID = 1, dbID = 17".

Overall number of entries in table data: 45.245.438
Overall number of entries in table details: 126.608.661

Now I would like to get the first 50 entries from table data which do not have the condition dbID = 4, sorted by data.numDB. The resulting query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(data.entry), data.numDB FROM blacklists.data data INNER JOIN blacklists.details details ON details.dbID NOT IN (4) AND data.id = details.dataID ORDER BY data.numDB DESC LIMIT 50
```

which (at least) takes 10 minutes of processing time (I stopped it after 10 minutes).

This is what EXPLAIN outputs:

EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT(data.entry), data.numDB FROM blacklists.data data INNER JOIN blacklists.details details ON details.dbID NOT IN (4) AND data.id = details.dataID ORDER BY data.numDB DESC LIMIT 50

```
id  select_type  table    type   possible_keys            key         key_len  ref                rows      Extra
1   SIMPLE       data     index  PRIMARY,entry_numDB_id   entry_numDB 261      NULL               45166874  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE       details  ref    dataID,dbID,dataID_dbID  dataID      8        blacklists.data.id  1        Using where; Distinct
```

Not using DISTINCT (or GROUP BY) results in entries being repeated multiple times.

Is there a way to improve this query? I already read many help pages and other questions and their answers but were unable to find a solution for these tables.

Comment: You can use temporary tables in this case. and can also use engine = memory (memory is faster), temporary tables are dropped by mysql after the connection is closed. So try using that. Also define heap table size parameter in the my.cnf aswell.

Comment: You state that you "would like to get the first 50 entries from table data which do not have the condition dbID = 4" - however, it appears that the query is asking for "the first 50 entries from table data which HAVE details which are not 'dbID = 4'" - which is correct?

Comment: I just tested it with temp tables in memory, however, it is still very slow. And I want to get all details with dbID != 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining details is kind of screwing you here. You aren't really filtering much out with the dbID != 4 hence it's still having to scan through most of table 'data'. This is an area where a subquery might help you out. Instead of querying all of table 'data' for what's effectively the last 50 rows + any rows that join table 'details' with a dbID == 4, maybe manually limit to the last couple thousand rows, or any approximation of what would not have a dbID == 4

I think you'll see a great performance gain by writing your query like this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(data.entry), 
        data.numDB 
FROM
    (
        SELECT x.entry, x.numDB, x.numDB
        FROM blacklists.data x
        ORDER BY x.numDB DESC LIMIT 2000
    ) data
INNER JOIN blacklists.details details 
    ON details.dbID NOT IN (4) 
    AND data.id = details.dataID 
ORDER BY data.numDB DESC LIMIT 50
```

Alter the limit in the subselect up or down to suit your needs. A smaller value will run this query faster, but possibly not come up with the 50 records you want, A larger value will run slower, but give you a better chance to get the 50 records you want.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd change `dbID NOT IN (4)` to `dbID <> 4`. It's possible that MySQL will optimize that correctly, but I'd like to be sure.

Second, I'd consider de-normalizing the data a bit, placing a field in `data` that represents the desired condition, allowing you to do a single-table query (which will work MUCH faster). This field can either be maintained in the application or with a trigger.

Comment: I used the "not in" on purpose as sometimes there are more dbIDs I want to exclude :)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you have a suggestion for the following query as well:

The details table stays the same as above and I further have

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ips` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dataID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `dataID_ip` (`dataID`,`ip`),
  KEY `dataID` (`dataID`),
  KEY `ip` (`ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I now want to get all IPs from that table which are not in dbID = 4, sorted by their count(ip):

What I do is:

```
SELECT ip.id, ip.ip, count(ip.ip)
FROM
    (
        SELECT x.id, x.ip, x.dataID
        FROM ips x
        GROUP BY x.ip ORDER BY COUNT(x.ip) DESC LIMIT 1000
    ) ip
INNER JOIN details details 
    ON details.dbID NOT IN (4) 
    AND ip.dataID = details.dataID 
GROUP BY ip.ip ORDER BY COUNT(ip.ip) DESC LIMIT 50
```

However the inner SELECT needs a full table scan.

```
1 PRIMARY <derived2> ALL       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1000     Using temporary; Using filesort
1 PRIMARY details    ref       dataID,dbID,dataID_dbID,dataID_active,dbID_active_...     dataID     8     ip.dataID     1     Using where
2 DERIVED x          index     NULL    ip     4     NULL    8960260     Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Is there any way to also improve this query?

Comment: I think, and I'm not sure on this and don't have your data to experiment on, that you are preventing any indexing by counting a specific column, unless ips.ip has the ability to be null (and by your DDL it does not) then you should `count(*)` to let mySQL decide how to count, and better choose which index to use. also put your count(*) in the subSelect select clause and give it an alias. MySQL will let you order and group by that alias, as well as have the parent select statement just pull that value, rather than having it run it's own separate count.